# geom_vline with Character xintercept

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have some ggplot code that worked fine in 0.8.9 but not in 0.9.1.

I am going to plot the data in `theDF` and would like to plot a vertical line at `xintercept="2010 Q1."`  `theGrid` is merely used to create `theDF`.

```
theGrid <- expand.grid(2009:2011, 1:4)
theDF <- data.frame(YrQtr=sprintf("%s Q%s", theGrid$Var1, theGrid$Var2), 
                    Minutes=c(1000, 2200, 1450, 1825, 1970, 1770, 1640, 1920, 1790, 1800, 1750, 1600))
```

The code used is:

```
g <- ggplot(theDF, aes(x=YrQtr, y=Minutes)) + 
         geom_point() + 
         opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90))

g + geom_vline(data=data.frame(Vert="2010 Q2"), aes(xintercept=Vert))
```

Again, this worked fine in R 2.13.2 with ggplot2 0.8.9, but does not in R 2.14+ with ggplot2 0.9.1.

A workaround is:

```
g + geom_vline(data=data.frame(Vert=4), aes(xintercept=Vert))
```

But that is not a good solution for my problem.

Maybe messing around with `scale_x_discrete` might help?

Comment: This isn't reproducible without `theVerts` (which I presume is a data frame?).

Comment: @joran I had `data=` in `aes` by accident.  It is fixed now, theVerts has been replaced by `data.frame(Vert="2010 Q2")`.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you file an issue at: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues

Answer (score 16):

You could try this:

```
g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = which(levels(YrQtr) %in% '2010 Q1')))
```

This avoids the need to create a dummy data frame for the selected factor level. The which() command returns the index (or indices if the right side of the %in% operator is a vector) of the factor level[s] to associate with vlines.

One caution with this is that if some of the categories do not appear in your data and you use `drop = TRUE` in the scale, then the lines will not show up in the right place.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I'll check to make sure that is generalizable to other data types.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a character vector, or a factor, for the x-axis in a plot the default values given to each of the unique items is simply integer starting at 1.  So, if your levels are c("A" "B", "C") then the x-axis locations are c(1,2,3).  There is no such thing as a character location, just a character label.  If you want a vertical line at A then put it at 1.  If you want it half way in between A and B then put it 1.5.  Again, those are the defaults.  If a particular plot did something else you can easily work that out by putting lines at a few locations and seeing what happens.

Comment: Yes, that is the case.  But in the old version of `ggplot2` if you fed it "A", it would translate that to 1 and place the line correctly.  This behavior is desirable because the user will know the original scale, not necessarily what it translates to.  I am hoping to recreate the behavior `ggplot2` used to exhibit.