# Adding conditional vertical line with x axis character

Tags: r, ggplot2

I couldn't find a way to do this even looking with this similar question at here [geom-vline-with-character-xintercept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093248/geom-vline-with-character-xintercept).

Basically, I try to add vertical lines to x values and vertical lines positions can be assigned with  `levels(theDF$YrQtr)[c(T, rep(F, 2))]` code.

but getting an error as shown below. I couldn't find out.

Reproducible example code;

```
theGrid <- expand.grid(2009:2011, 1:4)
theDF <- data.frame(YrQtr=sprintf("%s Q%s", theGrid$Var1, theGrid$Var2), 
                    Minutes=c(1000, 2200, 1450, 1825, 1970, 1770, 1640, 1920, 1790, 1800, 1750, 1600))

ggplot(theDF, aes(x=YrQtr, y=Minutes)) + 
         geom_point() + 
         theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept =  levels(theDF$YrQtr)[c(T, rep(F, 2))]))
```

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (12): xintercept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't have to use `aes` for the `geom_vline`. You just need to provide the values. Second, `ggplot` will transform the character variable into numeric when producing the plot. Hence, you need to transform the value as well. You can do it by adding `seq_along`. It implicitly changes the character into numeric values (1, 2, 3...).

```
ggplot(theDF, aes(x=YrQtr, y=Minutes)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))+
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq_along(levels(theDF$YrQtr))[c(T, rep(F, 2))])
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that!